# R: Add horizontal and vertical braces to boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot, braces

I'm new here and have very limited skills in R.  I'm nearing the completion of my MSc dissertation and need to use R to make some basic graphs, but I'd like to take some to the next level - but I really need some help :(.  I can do the basics, but I'm trying to add a few 'impressive' elements to my graphs.

I'll try and be as specific as I can be.

[image]

```
boxplot(Ex.E~Thing, data=Graph, ylim=c(0,5), ylab = expression(bold("Chance of Illness (%)")), xlab= expression(bold("Predicted Water Quality and Acceptable Level of Risk")))

abline(h = 1, lty=2)
abline(h = 5, lty=3)
```

Thats the charts I currently have and the code I've used.

I'd like to add braces on the horizontal axis and axis on the right.

[image]

Excuse my poorly drawn graph, but thats what I'm aiming for - if anyone can help me out?

I've look about, but can't get my head around how I do this :(!  Any help would be greatly appreciated :)!

Cheers,

Ross

Comment: Use a tool designed for that. ImageMagick comes to mind.

Comment: have a look at the answer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869526/plot-curly-bracket-for-axes-area