# construct a curly bracket (}) of variable height in R

Tags: r, lattice, typography, r-grid

I am using lattice to build a figure.  It should contain curly brackets (}) that differ in height but that all have the same width.  Is there a way to do "draw" such brackets in R?

It is easy to use `grid.text`, `panel.text`, etc. to add brackets, or any other text, to a figure.  But with any font -- even a monospaced font -- brackets that have a larger height will also have a larger width.  That isn't acceptable for my current figure.  I need to "stretch" some brackets vertically without stretching them horizontally.

The method that comes mind is to stitch together many different line segments to create something that looks like a bracket.  But this will be difficult.  Is there any other way?

Others have asked related questions.  For example, at [ggplot2: Curly braces on an axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001799/ggplot2-curly-braces-on-an-axis), another user asks about using ggplot2 to add curly brackets to a plot.  But as the commenters who respond to that post concede, the solutions that they offer are klugey -- and in any case, I am looking for a lattice-based solution, not a ggplot2-based solution.  I am also looking for a solution that can create brackets of differing height while holding width constant; this problem isn't taken up in other posts.

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7001799/324364) method work?

Comment: That method uses grid so it should work, even though it is labeled as involving ggplot.

Comment: @joran: thank you.  I still haven't found a function that lets one specify the endpoints of the bracket –– e.g., y1 and y2 for the top and bottom of the bracket.  Such a function would be ideal.  But the method to which you linked can be made to work.  That said, I went instead with a slightly different method––[your own](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6179288/697473).