# Is there a good way to display Intervals in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, model, intervals

I am writing an essay and would love to portray the dimensions I am studying as intervals. To enable this, I want to explain this with a model, a little like the picture below.
Is there a way to implement this in R? I would really love for it to have color! Thanks all of you in advance.

[image: Interval Model]

Comment: What should be in color?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178763/how-to-add-braces-to-a-graph

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001799/ggplot2-curly-braces-on-an-axis

Comment: well either the intervals or the different sections