# How to Create a Curly Brackets in Julia with Plots?

Tags: julia

I want to create a bracket like this:

[image]

I currently use a line and two bars to replace the bracket, I try to use } with rotation and increase the length and it is not working.

this is my code:

```
using Plots, LaTeXStrings
gr()

x = collect(range(0, 4, length= 100))
f(x) = sqrt(4x)
g(x) = (4x - 4)/3

plot(g,-1,4, xtick=-1:1:4, xlims=(-1,4), ylims=(-2,4), 
    framestyle=:zerolines,
    label=L"g: 4x - 3y = 4", legend=:topleft)
plot!(f,-1,4, xtick=-1:1:4, xlims=(-1,4), ylims=(-2,4), 
    framestyle=:zerolines,
    label=L"f: y^{2} = 4x ", legend=:topleft)

plot!(x, f, fillrange = g, fillalpha = 0.35, c = 1, 
    label = L"f - g = y^{2} - 3y - 4 = 0", legend=:topleft)

plot!([0.42,1.95],[f(0.42),g(1.95)], label="", linecolor=:green)
plot!([0.3,1.8],[f(0.3),g(1.8)], label="", linecolor=:green)

annotate!([(0.27,1.27, (L"△ y", 8, :blue))])
annotate!([(1.95,0.97, (L"y_{i}", 8, :blue))])
annotate!([(2.13,1.17, (L"y_{i+1}", 8, :blue))])

plot!([0.45,1.97],[1.5,1.5], label="", linecolor=:blue)
annotate!(0.45,1.5, Plots.text("|", 10, :blue, rotation = 0 ))
annotate!(1.97,1.5, Plots.text("|", 10, :blue, rotation = 0 ))

annotate!([(1.41,1.7, (L" \frac{3y+4}{4} - \frac{y^{2}}{4}", 6, :blue))])
```

Edited:
I am able to make the curly bracket with the help of the Bezier Curve, only small thing left, how to rotate it 180 degree so it will face to bottom?

```
using Plots
gr()

using Plots, LaTeXStrings, InverseFunctions
gr()

x = collect(range(0, 4, length= 100))
f(x) = sqrt(4x)
g(x) = (4x - 4)/3

function Area(f, a, b, n)
xs = a:(b-a)/n:b
deltas = diff(xs)
cs = xs[1:end-1]
sum(f(cs[i]) * deltas[i] for i in 1:length(deltas))
end

r1 = round(Area(y -> (3y + 4 - y^(2))/(4), -1, 4, 50000), digits=5)

plot(g,-1,4, xtick=-1:1:4, xlims=(-1,4), ylims=(-2,4), 
    framestyle=:zerolines,
    label=L"g: 4x - 3y = 4", legend=:topleft)
plot!(f,-1,4, xtick=-1:1:4, xlims=(-1,4), ylims=(-2,4), 
    framestyle=:zerolines,
    label=L"f: y^{2} = 4x ", legend=:topleft)

plot!(x, f, fillrange = g, fillalpha = 0.35, c = 1, 
    label = L"f - g = y^{2} - 3y - 4 = 0", legend=:topleft)

plot!([0.42,1.95],[f(0.42),g(1.95)], label="", linecolor=:green)
plot!([0.3,1.8],[f(0.3),g(1.8)], label="", linecolor=:green)

annotate!([(0.27,1.27, (L"△ y", 8, :blue))])
annotate!([(1.95,0.97, (L"y_{i}", 8, :blue))])
annotate!([(2.13,1.17, (L"y_{i+1}", 8, :blue))])

#plot!([0.45,1.97],[1.5,1.5], label="", linecolor=:blue)
#annotate!(0.45,1.5, Plots.text("|", 10, :blue, rotation = 0 ))
#annotate!(1.97,1.5, Plots.text("|", 10, :blue, rotation = 0 ))

annotate!([(1.41,1.9, (L" \frac{3y+4}{4} - \frac{y^{2}}{4}", 6, :blue))])

# Create curly bracket
topy = 1.5

# Left bracket starting from 0.143239π, and ending at the middle at 0.3851545π 
bezxl = [0.143239π, 0.143239π, 0.3851545π, 0.3851545π] 
bezyl = [2, topy, 2, topy]
curves!(bezxl, bezyl; linecolor=:blue, label="left")

# Right bracket starting from the middle at 0.3851545π and end at 0.62707π
bezxr = [0.3851545π, 0.3851545π, 0.62707π, 0.62707π]
bezyr = [topy, 2, topy, 2]
curves!(bezxr, bezyr; linecolor=:blue, label="right")

# Type at julia REPL after finish to gain the area' approximation: r1
```

[image: current progress]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for that

```
using Plots

plot(sin; xlim=(0, 2π))

topy = 0.4

bezxl = [π/2, π/2, π, π]
bezyl = [0, topy, 0, topy]
curves!(bezxl, bezyl; label="left")

bezxr = [π, π, 3π/2, 3π/2]
bezyr = [topy, 0, topy, 0]
curves!(bezxr, bezyr; label="right")
```

The example above uses [Bezier curves](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/api/#Plots.curves-Tuple).

[image]

Also what I've found...

*Disclaimer: My micro-research (googling, actually) does not pretend to be complete and correct.*

- Seems like textual type of Plots.jl isn't compatible with Shape type. For the latter there are transforming tools. I'd imagine when sometime we can say  "scale text along y axis, then rotate". E.g., in R, as I understand, [it's possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178763/how-to-add-braces-to-a-graph).
- One crazy idea is to find a typeface, where line height and width of curly brace symbol is disproportional as needed...
- So, the next idea came to my mind is to plot a function that looks like curly brace...
- Here is a [matlab implementation](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38716-curly-brace-annotation) of curly brace drawing. Seems like, the author defines it as partial function.
- Also I've found [a reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/mathmemes/comments/m3u7ev/i_made_a_function_that_outputs_endless_curly/) where someone find equation for 2d tessellation by curly braces.
- After all, I remembered that there are Bezier curves. Hopefully, Plots.jl supports them.

Comment: No need for sorry, everyone make mistakes / sins.. haha. Thanks for this, Bezier Curve? What a solution... The origin of Bezier Curve is to create a curve in a beautiful car..

Comment: Your code works great, I modify a bit, only need to make it upside down now..

Comment: Done , the key is to play with `topy` if it is higher then the number `bezyl` or `bezyr` it will facing down, otherwise it will facing up